# How to recover trash can icon in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever you enable terminal integrated tabs in Visual studio code, it replaces the default trash can icon and spilt-terminal option with a terminal dropdown. It is helpful but not in cases when you're occasionally killing the terminal.
[Terminal without the trash can icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmYKj.png)

So, How to recover that trash can icon?

Answer (score 4):

To recover the trash can, open the `setting.json` file in your VS code and set the `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,` to false.
[recovered trash can icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbODl.png)